# Change url Angularjs

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs

I'm learning Angularjs and I'm doing the tutorial from http://angularjs.org/, but I'm unable to get what I want. I have a simple page, index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="helloWorld.html">Hello World</a></li>
      <li><a href="tasks.html">Tasks</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want that when I click on `projecst.html` my url shows something like `http://localhost:8080/Application/projects` or `http://localhost:8080/Application/#/projects` or `http://localhost:8080/Application/#!/projects` or whatever, but I don't want that it shows `http://localhost:8080/Application/projects.html`
I've been testing with `$routeProvider`, `$locationProvider` and `$location`, but I don't undestand very well how they work, Can anybody explain it to me? Can anybody help me with this issue?

More information:
projects.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="project">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS | Projects</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://firebase.github.io/angularFire/angularFire.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/projects.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Projects</h2>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

project.js:

```
angular.module('project', ['firebase']).
  value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/').
  factory('Projects', function(angularFireCollection, fbURL) {
    return angularFireCollection(fbURL);
  }).
  config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {templateUrl:'list.html', controller:ListController}).
      when('/edit/:projectId', {templateUrl:'edit.html', controller:EditController}).
      when('/new', {templateUrl:'edit.html', controller:NewController}).
      otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Greetings.

Comment: May I recommend [the thinkster.io tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GtaQ0oMGIl/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs) for learning angular.js - it's fairly long but it's worth it. The egghead.io videos that it references are also quite nice for bitesize chunks, but they do need some supplementing with docs and/or other material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the URL using the `$routeProvider` http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 . don't point your href to *html. point them to the urls you defined.

then you can also configure the `$routeProvider` to be either in HTML5 mode or in hashbang (default) mode-

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using "index.html" as your host page and deploy on a real webserver.
You could also configure your webserver to accept "projects.html" as an index file or welcome file.

You then setup routing in your angular application like so:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/projects', {
templateUrl: 'partials/project-list.html',
controller: 'MyCtrl'
});
}]);
```

Make sure to link to that in a correct way, so your html should be

```
<li><a href="#!/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
```